# Accessing Object variable

Tags: php, oop, object

I'm using an API that results an array like this when there is data:

```
object(stdClass)#38 (5) {
  ["ReturnCode"]=>
int(1)
["EntityResults"]=>
object(stdClass)#39 (1) {
  ["Entity"]=>
  object(stdClass)#40 (15) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(43622)
  ["UserDefinedFields"]=>
  object(stdClass)#41 (0) {
  }
  ["TicketID"]=>
  int(31024)
  ["InternalAllocationCodeID"]=>
  int(28303142)
  ["Date"]=>
  string(19) "2011-03-24T00:00:00"
  ["StartDateTime"]=>
  string(19) "2011-03-24T11:41:00"
  ["EndDateTime"]=>
  string(19) "2011-03-24T11:46:00"
  ["HoursWorked"]=>
  float(0.08)
  ["HoursToBill"]=>
  float(0.0833333358)
  ["OffsetHours"]=>
  float(0)
  ["SummaryNotes"]=>
  string(584) "Hi Steve..."
  ["InternalNotes"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["RoleID"]=>
  int(24482927)
... 

... 

... 

...
```

Then I have some record that return the results:

```
object(stdClass)#33 (5) {
["ReturnCode"]=>
int(1)
["EntityResults"]=>
object(stdClass)#34 (0) {
}
["EntityResultType"]=>
string(9) "timeentry"
["Errors"]=>
object(stdClass)#35 (0) {
}
["EntityReturnInfoResults"]=>
object(stdClass)#36 (0) {
}
```

}

With this last result I get an error

> everity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property:
>   stdClass::$Entity
>
> Filename: models/tickets_model.php

My question is how can I avoid getting this error? I've tried

```
    if($result->queryResult->EntityResults->Entity):
        $noteso = $result->queryResult->EntityResults->Entity;
        if(count($noteso)):
            return $noteso;
        else:
            return false;
        endif;
    endif;
```

But then I get the same error but in the IF statement.

Hope there's enough here for someone to understand what's happening.

Most appreciated with any help,

Billy

Comment: Have you considered just casting to array?  You'll have to do this recursively though with a small convenience function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you want:

```
if(isset($result->queryResult->EntityResults->Entity)):
```